# overlay image with shape css

Tags: html, css, web

How can I mask an image with a css shape?

**reference Image**

[image]

I already made a shape with css border style but not able to overlay an image.

**CSS**

```css
#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - SVG**

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="a" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="0,0 100,0 50,100" fill="url(#a)" />
</svg>
```

**Tested on Chrome, Firefox, IE9+**

---

**Option 2 - `clip-path`**

```css
.element {
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ok/128.jpg" />
</div>
```

- [can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)
- Grate tutorial about `clip-path`: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/
- Tool for generate shapes in this way: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Thanks, but mozilla is not supporting clip-path

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer.. That's why I added the SVG solution..

Comment: Yeah . Thanks. SVG works

Answer (score 2):

For that you can use `gradients`. Here is an example code:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, white 50%, transparent 0),        
    url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**[Working fiddle](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/pbPgym)**